# Why HDFS is necessary for HBase ?

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase, hdfs, bigdata

This question came into my mind today regarding HBase & HDFS.

Why only HDFS as storage for HBase, why not linux file system.

appreciate your reply.

Thanks

Comment: because it is a distributed file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase uses HDFS for its reliability. when HBase saves any piece of data to disk it relies on the fact that HDFS will replicate it to other nodes (3 by default). It uses the notification from the other nodes that they'd received the data before acknowledging a write. When HBase needs to reallocate a region it will,again, rely on HDFS to get a local copy of the data (if the region is not available locally it would read it remotely but it would try to get a local copy) etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `HDFS` provides scalability and reliability (by replicating data blocks to different machines). And `HBase` takes advantage of these features.

If `HBase` would have not used `HDFS` as an underlying filesystem it would need to have "somthing like HDFS" built-in anyway.